# SPD 2013 cannot edit forms

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, permissions

I have a subsite where I have owner permissions: I can create and run workflows, can create new forms, but I **cannot modify** them! Even the just created forms appear highlighted in yellow and "advanced mode" icon disabled.

[image]

I can guess there is a problem with permissions, but unfortunately, I have no access (with owner permission) at site collection level. 
I have been checking on any list and/or library in the site and always have the same issue. In other sites I can do anything with forms - so it is not a SPD issue.

Some idea where to check?

Comment: could you check this https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/2154/unable-to-edit-site-in-sharepoint-designer-2010

Answer (score 1):

could be several issues. Make sure that your account has custom scripts enabled.

next phase would be to make sure that you are using the correct account to edit the forms. Logout from sharepoint using Internet explorer and then navigate to your site from SPD.

You could also check on SPD what account is currently running. 
click on file ->  account

issue is either your using wrong account or the account or site that you are using doesn't have the correct privileges to edit the forms in SPD and you can check if it does have this enabled for the site by going to "/_layouts/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx"

More detailed explanation here from Microsoft:

[Manage Permissions and Control Access to Sharepoint Designer](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2592376/manage-permissions-and-control-access-to-sharepoint-designer)

Comment: Thanks, I'll go step by step basing on MS page you linked. I don't know what happens when SPD is not enabled at site collection level... I see I can created and run workflows, so I thought it is not the case.

Comment: did you go to /_layouts/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx to check what is enabled for sharepoint designer?

Comment: I have no access there... trying to get it, but it means something...

Comment: sorry that was for sharepoint online. You need to do this on the server in central admin, follow this guide https://redmondmag.com/articles/2015/03/19/sharepoint-designer-tool.aspx

Comment: I am on Sharepoint online, your suggestion is right, but I am afraid the settings of the SC are bad, just I cannot see them...

Comment: strange you should be able to see the settings. Is this a site collection admin account that your using?

Comment: No, I have received only the sub-site full permission, but no permission of parent site (I can't even know is it site collection or sub-site). I start thinking maybe I need designer permission on site collection, but so far I could not find information about it

Comment: would explain why you cant see it and probably why you cant create/edit in SPD because settings need to be changed (enabled) for you to do that.

Comment: I know... but what is weird is that even in this site, on SPD I can create and run workflow, I can create and delete forms... but cannot edit them!

Comment: click on cog "top right" -> click on site settings -> what do you see under "site collection Administration" ? is it visible? youll know if you are at site collection level then becuase it will say to "go to top level site settings" means your in sub site. Also you would need designer or owner permission level and would need to have SPD active on the site for it to work

Comment: No, it is no visible. I know I am not at SC level... just cannot know at which level of subsite. I have full permission in the site (that is a subsite), but it does not help, I cannot edit forms. I can create or delete them, but not editing!

Comment: Yes that is my point you do not have the correct permissions for the site. If you have full permission to the site you would see /_layouts/SharePointDesignerSettings.aspx page but you dont indicating you need the correct permission to the site. Make sure you are either admin to site or at least owner or designer.

Comment: Finally I realized that that site had something weird: it was created and modified by somebody not expert at all. He also created infopath forms... I guess something went wrong. By chance this was the really start of the development, so finally rather that spending hours in investigation (by the way not even having SC permissions...) I have created a new one in a proper environment, and of course all goes smoothly.
Thanks for your help anyway.